# Excel Unprotects Sheet after VBA Code Crash Despite File Not Being Saved

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel book used by colleagues that is protected when they open it, when testing a new feature I was developing I have encountered an odd quirk with Excel that I don't understand:

When clicking a button linked to a Macro, the VBA code begins by unprotecting the workbook, like this:

```
Sub ButtonClick()
Dim userrange As Variant
Dim rrow As Range
Dim teeth As Range

' unprotect sheet
ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
Application.EnableEvents = False
```

The macro then crashes (I know why, that's not the issue here). I then press end on the error message pop up, and close excel without saving the file. When the file is reopened, the book is unprotected.

Essentially, the code crashes before it gets here:

```
' protect sheet
ActiveSheet.Protect ("password")
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

**Can I ensure the excel file is still protected when reopened, even when the VBA code crashes after unprotecting it?**

The reason this is an issue is that I have some existing functionality in the workbook that only works properly when the workbook is protected. So if somebody crashes the program then tries to reopen it, they cannot use it normally again without my input.

I find it odd that Excel 'saves' the fact that the workbook was unprotected, even if I close the file without saving anything. I'm aware some 'stuff' happens in the background when running a VBA code, for example the undo stack is cleared, I'm guessing something in the background is recording the fact the worksheet has been unprotected even if I don't save the file? I'd like to understand the mechanism, if anybody has an explanation of how the protection status is recorded, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Use error handling and as part of that re-protect the sheet

Comment: @Tom Can you explain how the workbook remains unprotected even if the file is not saved? That is fundamentally what I would like to understand. I guess it's a background process, in the same way the undo stack is cleared when you run a VBA code.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you could ensure the file is protected at open using the Workbook_Open event (add to ThisWorkbook module). This doesn't explain how the workbook currently remains unprotected, but you should be able to circumvent that.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

' Ensure sheets are protected at open
ActiveSheet.Protect "password"

End Sub
```